# Jq --- converting nested json to csv

Tags: jq

I have sample JSON like below

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "city",
      "LIST": {
        "ID": [
          {
            "value": "ny",
            "name": "US"
          },
          {
            "value": "lon",
            "name": "GB"
          },
          {
            "value": "Toronto",
            "name": "CA"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "city1"
    }
  ]
}
```

I was to get value as below

```
city,ny

city1,
```

I want only value where name="US" in `jq`.

There will be maximum of 1 `name` = "US" for each element of the `data` array. If there is no `name` = "US" then I want it as blank or NULL. In above example, if 2nd record doesn't have `name` = "US" then output will be `city1,blank` or `city1,`.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried jq -r '.data[] | select(.list.id[].name="US") | .list.id.value|@csv'  1.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that each `data` element has *at most* one element in its `.LIST.ID` array whose `name` equals `US`:

```bsh
jq -r <file '.data[] |
  [ .name, (.LIST.ID[] | select(.name == "US").value)? // null ] |
  @csv'
```

What it does:

1. returns (keeps) all the elements of the `data` array;
2. for each element of `data`, creates a two-element array (needed for CSV formatting) made of:

   1. the value of the `name` property of each `data` element;
   2. the value of the `value` property of the element of the `.LIST.ID` array whose `name` equals `US`, if any (`null` if there is none; you may use `""` in place of `null` to get a double quoted field in the CSV output in place of a completely empty field); the `?` after the parenthesised expression ensures no error occurs even if the `.LIST` or `.ID` elements happen to be completely missing;
3. renders the resulting list of arrays as CSV data.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the same as [fra-san's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/647195/116858), but using the fact that the elements of the `.LIST.ID` array can be turned into objects where the `name` values are keys and the `value` values are the corresponding values:

```bash
jq -r '.data[] | [.name, (.LIST.ID | from_entries? | .US) // "blank"] | @csv' file
```

With the given example data as input, this would produce the following header-less CSV data:

```
"city","ny"
"city1","blank"
```

Change `// "blank"` to `// null` in the `jq` expression to generate an empty field when the second field is not available in the data.